# C language. How to add strings to linked list

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

For some reason i cant get this working.  here is my function in the code, if this isnt enough to help, i will happily post the whole code.

```
char addcity()
{
    citylist=malloc(sizeof(struct city));
    struct city *temp;
    char addcity[50];
    char addstate[50];
    char addpopulation[50];
    char addregion[50];
    char addzipcode[50];
    //temp = citylist;
    //citylist=malloc(sizeof(struct city));
    //struct city *ptr=citylist;
    struct city *ptr= (struct city*)malloc(sizeof(struct city));
    printf("Which city would you like to add?: ");
    scanf("%s",addcity);
    printf("Which state is the city in?: ");
    scanf("%s",addstate);
    printf("What is the population?: ");
    scanf("%s", addpopulation);
    printf("what is the region?: ");
    scanf("%s", addregion);
    printf("what is the zipcode?: ");
    scanf("%s", addzipcode);
    int found;
    ptr->name=addcity;
    ptr->statecode=addstate;
    ptr->population=addpopulation;
    ptr->region=addregion;
    ptr->zipcode=addzipcode;
    ptr->next=NULL;

    curr->next=ptr;
    curr=ptr;

    printlist();  //this just prints out the whole list.
```

sometimes i get a segmentation error, and other times it just doesnt work at all.  do i have to use strcpy(a,b) to copy strings.

Comment: Please do not post a wall of uncommented code and ask us to debug it for you.  Put yourself in our shoes - would you help someone who was asking a question like this?  Please demonstrate that you've made at least a basic effort to debug this yourself.  Give us output from the debugger, the program, etc.  Finally, give us a piece of code that we can compile on its own to reproduce the bug.  Otherwise, we have no way of knowing the bug isn't someplace else.

Comment: Maybe you need to read up about pointers http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch1x.htm

Comment: Stepping through this in a debugger might help. Also, understanding pointers and C scoping might help as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("Which city would you like to add?: ");
scanf("%s",&ptr->name);
printf("Which state is the city in?: ");
scanf("%s",&ptr->statecode);
printf("What is the population?: ");
scanf("%s",&ptr->population);
printf("what is the region?: ");
scanf("%s",&ptr->region);
printf("what is the zipcode?: ");
scanf("%s",&ptr->zipcode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems in your code. Your first problem is that you are setting pointers in a structure to point at local variables. Once the code leaves `addcity()`, those local variables will no longer be valid and anything trying to use them will get into trouble.

To copy the local strings to your structure, you will need to use some form of string copy function, such as `strcpy(a,b)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Enter String ::");
scanf("%s",&ptr->str);
```